# Using scikit-learn OrthogonalMatchingPursuit module on continuous data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to use matching pursuit to construct sparse representations of consecutive time windows of continuous neural data and to ultimately detect events occurring in the data. I have attached a snapshot of some of my [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgwJx.png), which shows the output of my wavepacket detector (raw data is blue, 40-100Hz Hilbert envelope is red, and wavepackets are multi-colored). As you can see, it contains oscillatory bursts (which we call wavepackets), that I would like to find sparse representations for. Ultimately, I would like to use these sparse representations to make a wavepacket detector. I currently use the power of a wavelet transform for detecting wavepackets, and I am trying to see if matching pursuit will be more accurate and computationally efficient (I have a fairly high false positive rate).

My understanding is that in the OMP module for scikit-learn there are no built in dictionaries (like the Gabor, DCT, wpsym, etc...) as is common in other matching pursuit toolboxes. Instead we must first train our own dictionaries from example data and training labels. I find this attractive, because we get to generate our own dictionaries, but I am having trouble seeing how I can do this with my data.

In the example provided in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_omp.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-omp-py) data is generate with make_sparse_coded_signal. This gives us y, X, and w, from which we are able to train a model. My neural data is a single continuous trace. I can divide it into time windows (let’s say 500 samples long), so that I run OMP on each 500-sample long window individually. But how do I get the labels? How am I to construct y, X, and w from my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I know the answer to my own question. It was badly posed, because you can't construct y, X, and w from your data. You try to reconstruct your data (y) by multiplying a set of dictionary elements (X) by a set of weights (w) such that y = Xw.

So you have to begin with a pre-designed dictionary (X) and then you run

```
omp = OrthogonalMatchingPursuit(n_nonzero_coefs=n_nonzero_coefs)
omp.fit(X, y)
```

to get the coeffs (w).

I was misled into thinking that you can get an optimal sparse dictionary from this function because I read the [paper](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~ronrubin/Publications/KSVD-OMP-v2.pdf) referenced in the documentation, which does indeed provide a K-SVD algorithm for generating efficient sparse dictionaries which can then be used for orthogonal matching pursuit.

If something here is incorrect then somebody please correct me.